# How can I disable Zathura's statusbar by default?

Tags: linux, unix, pdf, zathura

I'd like to hide the statusbar by default when opening Zathura (Which is normally done with ***^n***)

image of the statusbar (HIghlighted at the bottom in the red box)
[image: Zathura status bar]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In zathurarc, use

```
set guioptions none
```

From the man pages

```
guioptions
       Shows  or  hides GUI elements.  When it contains 'c', the command line is showed.  When it
       contains 's', the statusbar is showed.

       · Value type: String

       · Default value: s
```

Even though the value "none" is not mentioned explicitly, it seems to work.

Comment: Works like a cham, thank you!